# VSCode to Visual Studio IDE code snippet conversion

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Consider the following VSCode code snippet taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69317230/492307):

```
 "var set get f m_":{
    "prefix": "varsetgetfm",
    "body":[
        "${1:int} ${2:VARNM};",
        "$1 ${2/^(?:f|m)_?([A-Za-z])(.*)|([A-Z].*)$/${1:/downcase}$2${3:/downcase}/}(){return $2;}",
        "void ${2/^(?:f|m)_?([A-Za-z])(.*)|([A-Z].*)$/${1:/downcase}$2${3:/downcase}/}($1 val){$2 = val;}"
    ]
  }
```

Is there a way to convert this and other snippets from VSCode to a format usable in Visual Studio IDE automatically without having to manually figure out the equivalent? Visual Studio IDE seems to have [xml based snippets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2019) and not json based snippets like VSCode does.

Comment: does VS allow field transformation

Comment: @rioV8 Your snippet was powerful. I do not know the answer to your question. I am using snippets only recently. Since VS has been around longer and is actually an IDE, I would hope that one can do stuff in it that one can do in VSCode as well.

Comment: @rioV8 FWIW, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/566576/visual-studio-ide-code-snippet-to-convert-field-fr.html
MS VSIDE folks seem to suggest that it is not a feature possible in VS IDE yet. :-(

Answer (score 1):

There’s no existing way. There’s however a way and it involves parsing the json and creating the xml needed.
You can use the schema reference [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippets-schema-reference?view=vs-2019) to see json <-> xml, snippet, equivalent.

In other words, make it yourself. Should be fairly easy given that all the details are already documented by Microsoft.

---

Next day edit:

Take a look at this gif I made [image: demo.gif]. It <strike>replicates</strike> partially replicates the vscode snippet inside visual studio.

Also, the snippet xml code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>varsetget</Title>
            <Shortcut>varsetget</Shortcut>
            <Description>Code snippet testing</Description>
            <Author>Dorian</Author>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Declarations>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>type</ID>
                    <ToolTip>the var type</ToolTip>
                    <Default>int</Default>
                </Literal>
                <Literal>
                    <ID>VARNM</ID>
                    <ToolTip>the var name</ToolTip>
                    <Default>VARNM</Default>
                </Literal>
            </Declarations>
            <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[
                $selected$$type$$end$ $VARNM$;
                $type$ $VARNM$(){return $VARNM$;}
                void $VARNM$($type$ val){$VARNM$ = val;}
            ]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

To be able to use it, create a `*.snippet` file wherever you want on your machine with the code above, then:

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]
4. [image]
5. Navigate and open the `*.snippet` file you created
6. [image]
7. [image]
8. [image]
9. You can now test out the snippet

**NOTE:** In Visual Studio 2019 the default of inserting a code snippet or moving to the next `Declaration` `Literal` is pressing `Tab` twice as opposed to Visual Studio Code, where only one `Tab` is needed.

---

Everything I wrote is from the [msdocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippets?view=vs-2019) or deducted from the examples there.

---

My last edit:

It looks like you're not out of luck. But I do not have the time to investigate/test further, sadly. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.package.expansionfunction?view=visualstudiosdk-2019

Also, according to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730156/get-namespace-in-a-code-snippet) you basically would have to create your own language, which I personally doubt.

PS: How come the guys at MS q&a didn't suggest this I do not understand...

Comment: I doubt that link is sufficient. For instance, in the VSCode snippet in the OP, there is a conversion automatically from upper case to lower case. How would one do that in a Visual Studio IDE code snippet? The link certainly offers no help or hint I can easily find.

Comment: You now ask for editor behavior, not literally replicating a snippet. Different things imo. Also no1 besides a human at ms working/ed in the project can tell you such detail (assuming it exists and undocumented). The only thing you/we have is that documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the details provided. However, your gif file does not do what @rioV8 's snippet does in VSCode. Please see https://imgur.com/LuBzSDF
Note that `VariableName` get converted to full lowercase `variablename` in the snippet code provided by @rioV8. In your case, `f_testASs` is the variable name. The function names continue to be the same. I want them to be `f_testass`. That is the essence of what I would like the snippet to achieve.

Comment: FWIW, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/566576/visual-studio-ide-code-snippet-to-convert-field-fr.html
 MS VSIDE folks seem to suggest that it is not a feature possible in VS IDE yet. :-(

Comment: Oh, I see now. Ty for the gif. I wouldn't have noticed. Well, would it bother you if you add three `Literals`? Type, fname and vname? Else I'm sorry but its ide limit like I said.

Comment: Actually, there is a bunch of other stuff in my actual workflow, where I don't have just 3 lines, but close to 8 lines that need to alternate between the actual UPPERCASE and lowercase stuff. So, being able to automate it without tabbing through 8 times and manually changing stuff from UPPER to lower is essential.

Comment: You may have a chance using the `Function` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippet-functions?view=vs-2019 abilities of the xml snipetting. I'll attempt it myself. You're welcomed to try it yourself in the mean time. Race you to it :D in theory (currently) you can pass the `fname` to the function and internally convert the param to lowercase or prety much neededCase.

Comment: this snippet does not replicate the OP snippet because it does not remove the `f_` in the function names

Comment: Thanks for digging through and unearthing these internals. It certainly seems quite complicated to do this.